# Import schema from one datatable to another?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Are there any commands that make life easy with respect to this?  I want to take the column schema of one datatable (.net datatable) and copy it to another new datatable.

Comment: why you need it? just create 2 instances of the same datatable

Comment: I want one of them to have no rows, meanwhile one is populated from some methods in my datalayer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer.  It is the .Clone method.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen something like:

```
SELECT * INTO [DestinationTable] FROM [SourceTable] WHERE (1=2);
```

Used in SqlServer.

I think this assumes that DestinationTable doesn't exist.  It then creates the table and copies the schema from SourceTable the WHERE clause prevents any actual data from being copied.

I'm not really a database developer, so there's probably a much better way to do this.

Comment: This may be correct, however I'm talking about datatables with respect to .Net.  Sorry if I was not clear